# How to extract keywords from bengali text using PHP

Tags: php, keyword, extract

I want to extract keywords automatically from Bengali text files using php.I have this code for reading a Bengali text file.

```
<?php
$target_path =  $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']; 
header('Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8');
$fp = fopen($target_path, 'r') or die("Can't open CEDICT.");
$i = 0;
while ($line = fgets($fp, 1024)) 
    {
        print $line;
        $i++;
    }
fclose($fp) or die("Can't close file.");
```

And I found following codes to extract most common 10 keywords but it's not working for Bengali texts. What changes should I make?

```
    function extractCommonWords($string){
      $stopWords = array('i','a','about','an','and','are','as','at','be','by','com','de','en','for','from','how','in','is','it','la','of','on','or','that','the','this','to','was','what','when','where','who','will','with','und','the','www');

      $string = preg_replace('/\s\s+/i', '', $string); // replace whitespace
      $string = trim($string); // trim the string
      $string = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]/', '', $string); // only take alphanumerical characters, but keep the spaces and dashes too…
      $string = strtolower($string); // make it lowercase

      preg_match_all('/\b.*?\b/i', $string, $matchWords);
      $matchWords = $matchWords[0];

      foreach ( $matchWords as $key=>$item ) {
          if ( $item == '' || in_array(strtolower($item), $stopWords) || strlen($item) <= 3 ) {
              unset($matchWords[$key]);
          }
      }   
      $wordCountArr = array();
      if ( is_array($matchWords) ) {
          foreach ( $matchWords as $key => $val ) {
              $val = strtolower($val);
              if ( isset($wordCountArr[$val]) ) {
                  $wordCountArr[$val]++;
              } else {
                  $wordCountArr[$val] = 1;
              }
          }
      }
      arsort($wordCountArr);
      $wordCountArr = array_slice($wordCountArr, 0, 10);
      return $wordCountArr;
}
```

Please help :(

Comment: Can you explain more `but it's not working for Bengali texts`. What's the exact problem (you doesn't get 10 words or get not proper 10 words or something else)?

Comment: @alexander.polomodov Bengali is a language and he is not able to get the text written in bengali.

Comment: @alexander.polomodov like for English sample text "This is some text. This is some text. Vending Machines are great." it will give the following outputs -
some,text,machines,vending
but for Bengali text like - "টিপ বোঝে না, টোপ বোঝে না
টিপ বোঝে না, কেমন বাপু লোক" output page is blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make simple changes:

- replace stopwords in `$stopWords` array with proper Bengali stopwords
- remove this string `$string = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]/', '', $string);` because Bengali sybmols doesn't match this pattern

Full code looks like:

```
<?php

function extractCommonWords($string){
    // replace array below with proper Bengali stopwords
    $stopWords = array('i','a','about','an','and','are','as','at','be','by','com','de','en','for','from','how','in','is','it','la','of','on','or','that','the','this','to','was','what','when','where','who','will','with','und','the','www');

    $string = preg_replace('/\s\s+/i', '', $string); // replace whitespace
    $string = trim($string); // trim the string
    // remove this preg_replace because Bengali sybmols doesn't match this pattern
    // $string = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]/', '', $string); // only take alphanumerical characters, but keep the spaces and dashes too…
    $string = strtolower($string); // make it lowercase

    preg_match_all('/\s.*?\s/i', $string, $matchWords);
    $matchWords = $matchWords[0];

    foreach ( $matchWords as $key=>$item ) {
        if ( $item == '' || in_array(strtolower(trim($item)), $stopWords) || strlen($item) <= 3 ) {
            unset($matchWords[$key]);
        }
    }
    $wordCountArr = array();
    if ( is_array($matchWords) ) {
        foreach ( $matchWords as $key => $val ) {
            $val = trim(strtolower($val));
            if ( isset($wordCountArr[$val]) ) {
                $wordCountArr[$val]++;
            } else {
                $wordCountArr[$val] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    arsort($wordCountArr);
    $wordCountArr = array_slice($wordCountArr, 0, 10);
    return $wordCountArr;
}

$string = <<<EOF
টিপ বোঝে না, টোপ বোঝে না টিপ বোঝে না, কেমন বাপু লোক
EOF;
var_dump(extractCommonWords($string), $string);
```

Output will be:

```
array(4) {
  ["বোঝে"]=>
  int(2)
  ["টোপ"]=>
  int(1)
  ["না"]=>
  int(1)
  ["কেমন"]=>
  int(1)
}
string(127) "টিপ বোঝে না, টোপ বোঝে না টিপ বোঝে না, কেমন বাপু লোক"
```

Comment: I tried that earlier. But it gave ��  �� 
Though I included
header('Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8');
if I encoded the output by utf8_encode(string) it gave ?? ??

Comment: Try new version of code. I change pattern to split text to words by space delimiter.

Comment: But I got
array(1) {
  ["��, "]=>
  int(2)
}
string(127) "টিপ বোঝে না, টোপ বোঝে না টিপ বোঝে না, কেমন বাপু লোক"

I don't know if it is any kind of configuration problem or not otherwise how come you got the answers but I didn't :(

Comment: Is your file in `utf-8` encoding? I run this code both on php 5.5 and php 7.0  and it works

Comment: Yeah ! its encoded in UTF-8 . My php version is 5.3.5
I encoded the files with notepad++ encoding option!

Comment: Oh!!! It worked finally !!! I updated my php version and now it's working!
Thank you so much @alexander